# Electron How to find out which process is executing common module?

Tags: electron

I have a common module named `LoggerService.js` which is used in main and renderer processor.

But now, i wrote a function in the module and i don't now how to check that module is loaded in main or renderer processor!

```
{
    log: function(message)=>{
        if( main processor )
        else
    } 
}
```

I think i have to write separate modules for each processor for example (`MainLogger.js` and `RendererLogger.js`).
Is that right? any idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your common module, you can test [process.type](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/process#processtype-readonly):

> `process.type` Readonly
>
> A `String` representing the current process's type, can be `"browser"`
>   (i.e. main process), `"renderer"`, or `"worker"` (i.e. web worker).

```
{
    log: function(message)=>{
        if( process.type === "browser" )
        else if( process.type === "renderer" )
        else
    } 
}
```